# How to generate a random jpeg in node?

Tags: node.js, random, jpeg

For testing of a cloud service, i have to upload a lot of pictures. But they have to be all different. How can i generate a jpeg with random content in node (or Javascript)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this node.js module random-image-generator [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/random-image-generator).

Usage (from link doc):

```
var randomImageGenerator = require('random-image-generator'),
    fs = require('fs');

randomImageGenerator(800, 600, function(err, image) {
    fs.writeFile('random-image.jpg', image, function(err) {
        // done, hopefully 
    });
});
```